# Change list domain swi-prolog clpfd

Tags: prolog, range, edit, clpfd

I'm using SWI-Prolog with clpfd library. The problem is that I generate a list of length `N` with items in `1..2^(N-1)`, constraining this list to have some properties and calculating the maximum of the ones that verify the constraint. After that I have to find the minimum of these maxima but there are too many cases to evaluate and Prolog ends to freeze.

```
maxConstrain(N,Max) :-
   listN(List,N),
   label(List),
   constrain(List),
   max_list(List,Max).

minMaxConstrain(N,M) :-
   findall(Max,maxConstrain(N,Max),Maxs), min_list(Maxs,M).
```

`listN(-List,+N)` generate a list with `N` items in `1..2^(N-1)`.

`maxConstrain(+N,-Max)` gives the maximum of `List` if it verify the constraint.

`minMaxConstrain(+N,-M)` gives the minimum of all the evaluations of `maxConstrain(N,Max)`.

Since I need the minimum of the maxima I thought to scale down the domain of the lists whenever I find a valid list with a maximum less than the original one. For example if I have `N=4` the elements of the list will be in `1..8`. Let's say I get two lists `List1` and `List2` with maximum `8` and `7` respectively. Now I have that every other valid list that contains `8` will be rejected since I have found `List2` with the maximum = 7 that is less than `8`. So my idea is to reset the range of the domain every time I find a maximum less than the previous. For example if the current domain is `1..Max1` and then I find `Max2 < Max1` then I will set the domain to `1..Max2`.

Is it possibile to do this?

Comment: With ECLiPSe you can do this because it has predicates like `dvar_domain/2`, `dvar_update/2`. I don't think there are also the same predicates available in SWI (at the least, i didn't find it on manual).

Answer (score 0):

The idea that you describe is what **branch-and-bound** algorithms do: you prune those parts of the search that cannot possibly lead to a better solution than the best one you have found so far.  Constraint solvers normally provide this functionality in some form.

For example, in ECLiPSe, this is provided by [library(branch_and_bound)](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/branch_and_bound/bb_min-3.html), and you would formulate your problem like

```
:- lib(ic).
:- lib(branch_and_bound).

min_of_max(N, Max) :-
    length(Xs, N),
    Xs #:: 1..2^(N-1),
    constrain(Xs),
    Max #= max(Xs),
    bb_min(labeling(Xs), Max, _).
```

By wrapping the `bb_min/3` call around the `labeling/1` search routine, any attempt to create a list whose maximum is greater or equal than the smallest maximum found so far will lead to failure.  By default, this is achieved by dynamically reducing the upper bound of `Max` (similar to the procedure you outlined in your question), but other strategy-options are available.